# XML parsing in python multi level tags

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to extract fields from a xml file with multiple levels of tags. In the following example,

```
  <compound kind="struct">
    <name>my-struct</name>
    <filename>struct____dt__args.html</filename>
    <member kind="variable">
      <type>int32_t</type>
      <name>count</name>
      <anchorfile>struct____dt__args.html</anchorfile>
      <anchor>a0fbe49d8b1189286bd817409658eb631</anchor>
      <arglist></arglist>
    </member>
    <member kind="variable">
      <type>int32_t</type>
      <name>create_type</name>
      <anchorfile>struct____dt__args.html</anchorfile>
      <anchor>a4e38c7f138891d020cce3c6d7e6bc31e</anchor>
      <arglist></arglist>
    </member>
    <member kind="variable">
      <type>size_t</type>
      <name>total_size</name>
      <anchorfile>struct____dt__args.html</anchorfile>
      <anchor>a41ca25bca63ad1fee790134901d8d1c0</anchor>
      <arglist></arglist>
    </member>
    </compound>
```

I need to parse this and extract fields in 'compound' tag (there are multiple compound tags with different kinds struct/function/class etc.,) I need only kind=struct tags followed by type and name of its children 'member' tags.

```
struct my-struct:
int32_t count
int32_t create_type
size_t total_size
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree


def extract_structs(xml_path):
    # data and xml structure validation omitted
    # result collected as lists and tuples without string formatting
    struct_list = []
    root = ElementTree.parse(xml_path).getroot()
    for compound in root:
        kind = compound.get('kind')
        if kind != 'struct':
            continue
        current_struct = []
        struct_list.append(current_struct)
        struct_name = compound.find('./name').text
        current_struct.append((kind, struct_name))
        for member in compound.findall('./member'):
            member_type = member.find('./type').text
            member_name = member.find('./name').text
            current_struct.append((member_type, member_name))
    return struct_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    structs = extract_structs('test_file.xml')
    print(structs)
```

Comment: This prints just an empty list for me.

Comment: Probably, you have a namespace within your root element, or compounds not a direct children of root. My code was based on unshown assumptions about your context. Show complete XML structure, please.